# Alternative way for Excel

Tags: excel

I have a large size excel file to process; for this loading into memory and updating the column in excel is very slow.

Is there an alternative tool that we can consider instead excel?

thanks in advance

Comment: Asking for advice on tools is off-topic on this site. You could do a google search, find a tool you like, and then come here with questions about that tool.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you could use python, load your excel file into a pandas dataframe, do your transformations in memory (very fast), then have the result in a new sheet in your Excel file, for example.

Some docs:

How to connect Excel and python: https://realpython.com/openpyxl-excel-spreadsheets-python/
Begginer guide to pandas:
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/10min.html

Comment: Thanks kelyen, currently i am using python only, if other then excel something like json, csv it would be better.